# Linux, top command, why "data" value and jvm -xmx param not equal?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu

In my tomcat server.xml, I set `JAVA_OPTS   -Xmx3072m;`

top command,  why show "DATA" column value is 3.8G?

[image]

Comment: I think Xmx is the heap limit for the Java program, there's also memory needed for the JVM itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-Xmx` switch is purely for the JVM's reclaimable heap (eg eden, tenured areas, etc). It doesn't cover space used by `PermGen` nor native resources. The DATA value returned by top is showing you the complete amount of memory used by the process.